# context.Wait issue while iterating

Tags: botframework

I am using bot framework c#. A start async method at RootDialoge is forwarding a call to the new class, later I want to call this class repetitively based on JSON file. That class not waiting at context.Wait() for input during the first iteration but working fine for next iteration.

Can you please tell me how these threads work internally and why its not able to wait for input on the first go.

```
RootDialog
public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
{
callJSON(context);
return;
}

private async Task callJSON(IDialogContext context)
{
//It will call LUIS API & get topScoringIntent
context.Call(new InstallSoftwareDyanamicFlow(topScoringIntent), this.ResumeAfterInstallSoftware);
} 

InstallSoftwareDyanamicFlowDialog:
public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
{
await callDynamicFlow(context);
return;
}

public async Task callDynamicFlow(IDialogContext context)
{
// It will get details from configuration file and pass-on one by one value using counter
context.Call(new CommonDialog(inputToIterate[counter].userInput, inputToIterate[counter].objectTypeRef, inputToIterate[counter].valuesToList, inputToIterate[counter].customMessage), this.ResumeAfterInstallSoftware1);
} 

CommonDialog Class:

public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
{
await context.PostAsync(customMessage);
**context.Wait(ResumeAfterStartAsync);**
}

public virtual async Task<IDialogContext> ResumeAfterStartAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
{
var receivedResult = await result;
var output = (JObject.Parse(((JValue)((JToken)JsonConvert.SerializeObject((await result)))).ToString()))["value"][userInput1];
var value = await result;
await context.PostAsync(value.ToString());
return context;
}
```

At this ResumeAfterStartAsync, it's coming directly without waiting for the user to input value only for first iteration i.e for counter=1 but working fine for counter=2 and so on.

Comment: It seems that you define constructor(s) for your InstallSoftwareDyanamicFlowDialog&CommonDialog class(es) and expect parameter(es), you did not share the complete code of your implementation, which is not enough to reproduce the issue, please share your complete code.

Comment: Its an enterprise code, I can't share it completely.
So I share important part out of it.
At InstallSoftwareDyanamicFlowDialog I am passing intent which then gets necessary parameter list from config file.
Later we are calling CommonDialog for all parameters using incremental counter variable.